# 2 обработчика JQURY

Tags: jquery

Как правильно сделать, чтобы по click и одновременно key - выполнялся код:

$('#FormComment #sendComment, #SendReplyComment').live('click', function() {
// ВЫПОЛНЯЛСЯ ТУТ КОД
});

Можно как-то в live('click') приписать и live("keypress")? Не хочется делать 2 события с идентичным телом функции просто...

Answer (score 1):

Про метод live() - пора забыть.

```
$('#FormComment #sendComment, #SendReplyComment').on('click keypress', function() { 
    // ВЫПОЛНЯЛСЯ ТУТ КОД 
});
```

И вот, что [получим в итоге](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/L5vru/2/).

Comment: А как дополнительно поставить условие, чтобы реагировал только на Enter при Keypass?   if (e.keyCode == 13) {} так чтобы и click работал независимо...

Comment: Например, [таким образом][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/L5vru/3/